# is it possible to make use of data stored using the user.data service ifor filtering views?

Tags: views

Allowing a user to bookmark a node i have created

```
 public function bookmark($nid,$uid) {
    $user_data = \Drupal::service('user.data');
    $bookmarked_nodes = $user_data->get('my_module', $uid, 'bookmark');
    $bookmarked_nodes[$nid] = $nid;
    $user_data->set('my_module', $uid, 'bookmark', $bookmarked_nodes);
    \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus(t('node bookmarked.'));
  }
```

i would like then to create a view listing only nodes that has been bookmarked by the current user.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Better use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module for a more robust bookmarking solution. Allows you to record a "flag" made by user (in this case, a bookmark) and has a ready-to-use Views integration to filter flags and relate the both user and the flagged entity.

Comment: The module is not stable yet

Comment: @Matoeil Unless you have a company policy against unstable modules or modules not covered by Drupal security, it's stable enough for use. I would use Flag than reinvent the same thing myself (and have something even more unstable). Besides, if you find any flaws, you can always patch the module yourself with [`cweagans/composer-patches`](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches).